# How to hide a UIButton during textView scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextview

I am making an iOS app which contains a detailed text under `UITextView`.I added a share button in the view beside a `UITextView`. I want the button to be hidden when the user starts scrolling and return back when scrolling is not detected.

What I did was this...
`if(detailDescriptionTextView.isScrollEnabled == true) 
{my button.isHidden = true }`

The above code hides the button entirely since scrollview is on by default. So what shall I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of `UITextView` inherits from `UIScrollView` you can use `UIScrollViewDelegate` method for this purpose. You need to just set the delegate of `UITextView` and implement below methods of `UIScrollViewDelegate` and you all set to go.

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if yourTextView = scrollView {
        yourButton.isHidden = true 
    }
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if yourTextView = scrollView {
        yourButton.isHidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nirav.But after implementing your code without detting delegates of the textvire,it doesn'twork.So,how to set the delegates of UITextView?

Comment: @Haileapp You can set delegate of `textView` in interface builder in storyboard or programmatically in viewDidLoad using `yourTextView.delegate = self`

Comment: ,when I added the delegate programmatically, it throws error saying  cannot assign Vale of type 'DetailTwo' to type 'UiTextViewDelegate?'. DetailTwo is the .Swift class of my detail component

Comment: @Haileapp Edit your question with your current code that's you are trying also add detail on which line you are getting that error

Comment: Many Thanks @ Nirav D...I've just added the texture and scroll view delegates in DetailTwo class and it works like a Charm!

Answer (score 2):

UITextView is a UIScrollView subclass. Therefore the UIScrollView delegate method you are using is also available when using UITextView.

you should use scrollViewDidScroll to detect scroll

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    button.isHidden = true
}
```

You can use scrollViewDidEndDecelerating . It will call when textView stop scrolling.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    button.isHidden = false
}
```